# How to use JFileChooser in a JTable to select files and display data in the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jfilechooser

I am trying to be able to implement JFileChooser to be able to select from two .txt files made from another program. I have a fairly simple JTable created that will load in the data from one of the .txt files depending on which path I give it. But I am lost on how to make a JTable implement JFileChooser to be able to select either file and have the data shown in the correct cells. Below is the code for the JTable and a small sample of data from one of the files

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Maingui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Maingui().createUI();
            }
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }

    private void createUI() {

        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTable table = new JTable();

            TableModel tableModel = new TableModel();
            BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader("/Users/Will/Desktop/BenchmarkSortIterative.txt"));
            String line;
            file.readLine();

            List<Line> iterativeList = new ArrayList<Line>();
            while((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
                String splits[] = line.split(" ");
                String digits = line.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
            }

            tableModel.setList(iterativeList);
            table.setModel(tableModel);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            frame.setTitle("Benchmark Sorter");
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } catch(IOException ex) {}
    }

    class Line {

        private int size;
        private int avgCount;
        private int coefCount;
        private int avgTime;
        private int coefTime;

        public int getSize() {
            return size;
        }
        public void setSize(int size) {
            this.size = size;
        }
        public int getAvgCount() {
            return avgCount;
        }
        public void setAvgCount(int avgCount) {
            this.avgCount = avgCount;
        }
        public int getCoefCount() {
            return coefCount;
        }
        public void setCoefCount(int coefCount) {
            this.coefCount = coefCount;
        }
        public int getAvgTime() {
            return avgTime;
        }
        public void setAvgTime(int avgTime) {
            this.avgTime = avgTime;
        }
        public int getCoefTime() {
            return coefTime;
        }
        public void getCoefTime(int coefTime) {
            this.coefTime = coefTime;
        }
    }

    class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Line> list = new ArrayList<Line>();
        private String[] columnNames = { "Size", "Avg Count", "Coef Count", "Avg Time", "Coef Time"};

        public void setList(List<Line> list) {
            this.list = list;
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames[column];
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return list.get(rowIndex).getSize();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Data from .txt**

```
Data Set Size (n): 100
Iterative Selection Sort Results: 
Average Critical Operation Count: 1090
Standard Deviation of Count: 770
Average Execution Time: 10340
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DICLAIMER: This answer was originally posted to a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419831/data-fails-to-appear-in-jtable) by the same user, so I'm reposting it here to keep everything in the same place for the sake of future readers.

You have multiple issues that need to be fixed before you can even begin to address the main problem -- the code you posted doesn't even compile.

This is your code, below. Can you spot the problem?

```
public void getCoefTime(int coefTime) {
    this.coefTime = coefTime;
}
```

It should read as follows (your compiler would have alerted you to the issue):

```
// this method should be a setter not a getter
// your code called for setCoefTime(), but that method didn't exist
public void setCoefTime(int coefTime) {
    this.coefTime = coefTime;
}
```

Your table model is missing a mandatory method. Any time you create an implementation which extends an Interface, you are required to implement all method signatures from that Interface. In your case, you're missing the following method, and again, your compiler would have warned you about the issue:

```
@Override
public int getColumnCount()
{
    return columnNames.length;
}
```

Your data file is organized in a less than desirable manner. You seem to have written it as if its primary function was to supply information to a person, rather than a program, so you have these nice labels oriented vertically instead of horizontally, even though you want your `JTable` to display horizontally.

Instead of

```
Average Critical Operation Count: 30791
Standard Deviation of Count: 32884
Average Execution Time: 282750
Standard Deviation of Time: 241038
```

you should have maybe a comma separated value (CSV) file, like

```
trial 1,30791,32884,282750,241038
trial 2,30791,32884,282750,241038
trial 3,30791,32884,282750,241038
trial 4,30791,32884,282750,241038
```

You were getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because your code was reading the line

```
Recursive Selection Sort Results:
```

as `line1`, and when you call `line1[1]`, there's nothing there. You `split` on colon, but there's nothing to the right of the colon, so the `split` method doesn't bother to make a new token.

Get rid of all the nice headers and such because you'll just have to read those lines and throw them away later -- they're worse than useless because they actually introduce problems when your code doesn't anticipate their presence.

Now, you seem to have based your file reading code on a misunderstanding of how files are read. Whatever your current understanding of file reading is, forget it and pretend you've never heard of it before. The goal is to read lines one by one, break the line up into chunks of data (we'll call them tokens) and package them into a `Line` object before moving to the next line -- we're not reading five lines at a time here.

This kind of stuff is no longer necessary once you organize your input data sensibly:

```
String[] line1 = file.readLine().split(":");
String[] line2 = file.readLine().split(":");
String[] line3 = file.readLine().split(":");
String[] line4 = file.readLine().split(":");
String[] line5 = file.readLine().split(":");
```

Now, all you have to do is something like this:

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)  
{  
    // for purposes of clarity, we're changing the name of your Line object
    // in this example to TrialRecord

    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
    TrialRecord record = new TrialRecord();
    record.setSize( Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
    // the rest of your code...
}
```

Fix all this stuff and your table will display your data.

Comment: (1+) yes, changing the way the data is stored in the text file is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for dumming this down to me my brain has been fried today.. However I understand everything up until the ```record.setSize( Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]); ``` Is there supposed to be an open ). If I close it there it will compile but when ran it will return will a "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException, at that specific line.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I copied and pasted from your code, but I seem to have stomped on that close paren. One more thing to add: when you do your `try/catch`, never leave an empty catch block. put `ex.printStackTrace();` in it so you don't silently consume error messages.

Comment: Thank you, I actually added that in. Following the stackTrace it leads back to the same line. would this be because it is parsing an empty string?

Comment: *would this be because it is parsing an empty string?* - We don't know what the data is in your file. If you followed the suggestion given here then the first token would be "trial 1", which is not a number. In any case add a System.out.println( …) to display the value of tokens[0]. This is basic debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The JFileChooser is really irrelevant to the question.

You need to start is to learn how to create your `List<Line>` ArrayList with data from the file so you can invoke the `setList()` method.

Start by hardcoding the filename that you want to read. Then create a BufferedReader to read the file.

Then for each line of data in the file you would:

1. parse the data to get your size, counts and times values
2. use the values from above to create an instance of your `Line` object
3. add the `Line` object to your ArrayList

When you are finished reading the file you then invoke the `setList(…)` method on your `StudentTableModel`.

So get the above logic working first with a hard coded file name. Then once that works you use the JFileChooser to get the file name dynamically.

Edit:

> I am not sure if I am parsing the data correctly

Tell us how the code you posted creates a `Line` object.

Why are you doing the split() on " ". It looks to me like the data is separated by a ":".

Based on the format of the file which appears to have 5 lines of data you need to parse separately so your code would need to be something like:

```
String[] line1 = file.readLine().split(":");
String[] line2 = file.readLine().split(":");
String[] line3 = file.readLine().split(":");
String[] line4 = file.readLine().split(":");
String[] line5 = file.readLine().split(":");

Line line = new Line();
line.setSize( Integer.parseInt(line1[1].trim()) );
…
line.setAvgTime( Integer.parseInt(line5[1].trim()) );
iterativeList.add( line );
tableModel.setList( iterativeList );
```

Comment: I believe I made the appropriate changes however I am not sure if I am parsing the data correctly.

Comment: If you were able to create a `Line` object then it was correct. I don't see anywhere in your code where you create a `Line` object. The real question is why are you even using a JTable. A JTable is used to display multiple rows of data in a column format. From what I can see you only have a single row of data.

Comment: The sample data is a single section. I need the JTable to display the columns as listed in columnNames By ten rows.

Comment: I changed the code to add the the five lines of data but if I run this it will not work because the array list is out of bounds.

Comment: *The sample data is a single section.* - well how do we know that? How can we make a suggestion if we don't have all the information. So then obviously my suggestion won't work. You need to restructure the code to read 5 lines of data at a time and then parse the 5 lines of data to create your `List` object. *it will not work because the array list is out of bounds.* - no idea what that means. Based on the code posted it is in the same method where you read the data. I can only give you the concept. It is up to you to understand the concept and then write the code.

Comment: I apologize I meant to put Sample data because I did not want to fold the question with the entire .txt file. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: *I did not want to fold the question with the entire .txt file* - we do not need the entire text file, but we do need to know the layout and the fact that it repeats every 5 records.

Comment: Well Yes that is the case here sorry for the confusion and wasting of your time.

Comment: This posting contains a concept you can use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62247146/131872.  In the example the file contains 5 (or 6) lines of data followed by a blank link. The blank link indicates a row of data has been read and the data is added to the model. In your case you can add 5 lines of data to a Vector, then you will need to parse the data in the Vector to create your `Line` object and add the `Line` object to your ArrayList. This will allow you to have looping code to read the entire file but only update the ArrayList every 5 rows.